# Use global variable in jQuery function and then set it

Tags: jquery, function, variables, methods, parameters

I want to make a function that updates a variable defined in the function parameters - the example below should set 'cargo' to '10'.

```
    var cargo = 0;
    function itemChange(action,item,x){
        if (action == "set"){
            item = x;
        }
    }
    itemChange("set", cargo , 10);
    console.log(cargo);
```

Instead I'm getting 0 back, as if the "item = x" is doing nothing - where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve with this code, could you be more explicit?

Comment: The 'cargo' variable begins at zero. I want to refer to it when I call the function and then set it to ten. I'm eventually going to have lots of different variables I want to pass through, with different actions (like minus, add, multiply etc). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you have is to assign the return value of the function. Like:

```js
var cargo = 0;

function itemChange(action, x) {
  if (action == "set") {
    return x;
  } else if (action == "unset") {
    return null;
  }
}

cargo = itemChange("set", 10);
console.log(cargo);

cargo = itemChange("unset", "");
console.log(cargo);
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Sorry to ask on top of this but using the 'return' would there be a way to 'add' this on to the existing variable?

Comment: If the variable is an object or array, js passed it by reference and not by value. If the variable is number, on the other hand, it passes as a value. That is why we need to return the new value.